# Logging sensor data, calculating rate of change, and data analysis support in python for raspberry pi

Tags: python, pandas, logging, calculation

***Edited to be more straightforward.***

https://github.com/sjgittins/KilnTemperatureLogger

**Link to sample csv data above in github cause I don't know how to append data to this site. Thanks in advance for all the ideas / support.**

Goal:  Log temperature in pottery kiln with MAX31855 temperature module and a badass K type thermocouple  for the 8+ hours it takes to heat up to 2300F, and keep track of rate of change of temperature while logging data to CSV and output to graph.

Current problem: I need to know how to calculate and display/plot the rate of change of temperature per hour (and smaller increments of time). When temperature rise rate falls below some value (say 200F/hr) I need to flip the next switch. Kiln has 6 switches, and costs a lot to run (220V single phase 50Amp).  I already have some code working (below) to log the data in a unique csv file, and plot it live.

While logging the data, and live graphing it, I am looking  for help to incorporate a calculated rate of change of temperature at different time intervals going backwards. Example, previous(1, 5, 10, 20 minutes) so I know when the temperature rise rate is getting low so I can flip the next switch on the kiln.

What I tried:  I tinkered about with pandas but it stopped logging the data when I introduced pandas treating the csv as a DataFrame.  Not sure if or where I add this line into the code, inside or outside the loop, or if a major overhaul to the layout is needed.

Hope this makes sense.  I appreciate any support and ideas that you may offer. THANKS IN ADVANCE.  Feel free to make any suggestions and modifications.  Thank you.

```
from RPi import GPIO
import board
import busio
import digitalio
import adafruit_max31855
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
from time import sleep, strftime, time
import datetime
import requests
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

#setup MAX31855 for configuration
spi = busio.SPI(board.SCK, MOSI=board.MOSI, MISO=board.MISO)
# create the cs (chip select)
cs = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D5)
max31855 = adafruit_max31855.MAX31855(spi, cs)

#setting up matplotlib doing an interactive
#plot, and creates the 2 lists that we be stuffing data into
plt.ion()
x = []
y = []

filename = 'KilnTemperature-' +str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")+'.csv')
os.chdir('/home/pi/Data/Kiln_Temperature_Data')

with open(filename, "a") as log:
    while True:
        tempC = max31855.temperature
        tempF = tempC * 1.8 + 32
        y.append(tempF)
        x.append(time())
        plt.clf()
        plt.scatter(x,y)
        plt.xlabel('time')
        plt.ylabel('Temp F')
        plt.plot(x,y)
        plt.pause(10)
        plt.draw()

        #log the data
        #log.write is the command, and the first portion with the "{0},{1}" means
        #its a string containing two placeholders separated by a comma, and 
        #ending in a new line ( \n ) 
        #the .format(1,2) is where the 2 strings are defined ({0},{1})
        #the strftime stands for string ftime? just remember this
        #it means the current date and time as a string
        log.write("{0},{1}\n".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),str(tempF)))

        print("Temperature: {} F ".format(tempF))
```

Comment: I run temp sensors on a pi.  I send date every 3 seconds through a SOAP flask API where I collate and do analytics on either a Mac, AWS EB, GCloud or Azure. i.e. do all the analytics on an environment with more capability than a pi.  I'm sure a pi could do more,  but I want it as a light weight interface between sensors and actual processing engine.  Works well and very reliably

Comment: This is good and interesting, but you've got a lot going on here. It is hard to know where to help. You need to get your data logging working before trying to plot and analyze. Once you're got the data logging done and have some sample data to share, come back and ask a more focused question.

Comment: Thanks.  I do have the graphing and logging working, but I can't figure out how to perform any analysis on the csv file.  As soon as I try to introduce pandas, it prevents the logging from occurring.  The code as is allows me to at least save and real time plot the data, but nothing beyond that.

Comment: Link to .py code and csv file with sample data taken overnight with thermocouple sitting on heating register.     https://github.com/sjgittins/KilnTemperatureLogger

Answer (score 1):

Answers to your questions are wide and open. I would like to share my perspective

**Temperature control**

Do you intend to use the rate of change of temperature to maintain the temperature of the  pottery kiln? If so, I would recommend you to consider a PID control solution.

If you are new to PID, please consider to read:

1. [PID Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller)
2. [Process Dynamics and Control in Python](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/)
3. [Build a PID Controller with Python 2019](https://onion.io/2bt-pid-control-python/)

When the door is opened, the temperature will drop. A PID solution would try to control the heater such that the temperature is raised quickly to its set-point temperature.

*If the answer is not, consider the next answer.*

**Rate of Change of temperature**

You would like to see the rate of change of temperature *visually* and *control* the heater.  If this is the case, plotting temperature versus time is already a good solution.

However, for normal industry process control, we compute rate of change of *something* as soon as we receive a new value of *something*.  The *something* could be temperature, voltage, current, etc.  This ensures that we could detect positive and negative change of *something* even it happens momentarily.

On the other hand, we calculate rate of change of *something* over another periods (such as 1, 5, 10, 20 minutes) only if *something* increases **monotonically**.

When the door of the pottery kiln is opened, the temperature will drop.

However, for the benefits of estimation of data size, and performance of the Pi, we should sample temperature and control the heater at periodic interval such as every 10 seconds.

**CSV files vs Database**

CSV files provide a simple mean to store and retrieve data.  However, it is not efficient to retrieve data over a specific time range.  You could consider:

1. Use an in-memory SQLite database to store the most recent data, such as the last 2 weeks.
2. If you need the data for analysis later, consider to have another SQLite database which stores the data in a file.  However, you are advised to prune to old data so that the file will not grow too big.

**KISS - Keep It Super Simple**

I would suggest you to break the solution into several Python programs:

1. Read the temperature, store it into the in-memory and file SQLite databases, and distribute to other programs that needed it (such as PID controller, data proxy for your Django application as web browsers are looking at the data)
2. PID controller which computes the on and off for the heater, and sends the command to the program that actually control the heater.
3. The program that control the heater
4. A program to purge oldest data from the file SQLite database

etc.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information!   I do not plan to utilize a PID controller for a few reasons (cost, complexity, concern of error state).  I am not familiar with SQL at all, so I will start doing research.  I was hoping I could KISS with a easy CSV file and a handful of columns running calculations and outputting data but that doesn't appear to as easy as I thought.   I will look into SQL for calculations, and keep CSV/graph in case SQL fails so I at least have visual.  Any SQL training recommendations? Thanks again! Glad I posted here, appreciate all the support thus far